# Prove that $\lim a_{n}=e$?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

> Given that $a_{1}=0$, $a_{2}=1$ and 
>   $$a_{n+2}=\frac{(n+2)a_{n+1}-a_{n}}{n+1}$$
>   prove that $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} a_n=e$

What I did:

It was hinted to prove that $a_{n+1}-a_{n}=\frac{1}{n!}$ which I did inductively. 
But then using this information now I get:

$a_{n+1}=a_{1}+\frac{n}{n!}=\frac{1}{(n-1)!}$ so $a_{n}=\frac{n-1}{n!}$.

Now $a_{n}$ is bounded above by $\sum_{k=0}^{n}\frac{1}{k!}$ which converges to $e$. I can't find a lower bound that converges to $e$ as well. I'm starting to think I was supposed to go about this differently.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You wrote $a_{n+1}=a_n+\frac{1}{n!}$, then just kept decreasing the index of $a_n$ while adding on $\frac{1}{n!}$s. But as the index decreases, the thing you add on needs to change too. For instance, $$a_4=a_3+\frac{1}{3!}=a_2+\frac{1}{2!}+\frac{1}{3!}=a_1+\frac{1}{1!}+ \frac{1}{2!} +\frac{1}{3!}. $$

Comment: Also, either it should state $a_0=0$ and $a_1=1$, or else the limit should be $e-1$.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Instead, you should have got:

$$a_{n+1} = a_n + \frac1{n!} = a_{n-1} + \frac1{(n-1)!} + \frac1{n!}= \cdots = a_1  + \frac1{1!} + \frac1{2!} + \cdots + \frac1{(n-1)!} + \frac1{n!}$$

i.e.

$$a_{n+1} = \sum_{k=1}^n \frac1{k!} = \sum_{k=0}^n \frac1{k!} - 1$$

Hence, the limit is actually $e - 1$.

If, instead, the sequence was defined as $a_0 = 0$ and $a_1 =1$, then the limit would have been $e$ (by the same reasoning as above).

Comment: Thank you! Just one question though: shouldn't it be $a_{n+1} = \sum_{k=1}^n \frac1{k!}$ instead?

Comment: @John11 you're welcome; no, but there was a typo and I fixed it

Comment: @John11 actually, no you are right and the current version does not answer the question as it is posed. But for the result to be correct anyway, it should've been $a_0 = 0$ and $a_1 = 1$.

Comment: Ok because otherwise it converges to $e-1$?

Comment: @John11 yes. I'll add that.

Answer (score 1):

Now you can use induction to show that $\displaystyle a_n=1+\frac{1}{2!}+\frac{1}{3!}+\cdots+\frac{1}{(n-1)!}$,

so then $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k!}=\color{red}{e-1}$